# Bootstrap contact form (php + ajax)

Tags: php, ajax, bootstrap

Все формы на php+ajax. Если не заполнено или некорректно заполнено поле, то поле выделяется красной границей, появляется подсказка под ней красного цвета, под кнопкой отправки всплывает - "Проверьте поля формы". Если всё введено правильно, после отправки формы всплывает под кнопкой - "Сообщение отправлено".

Протестировала каждую форму, работали корректно.
Потом у меня вылетел Adobe Dreamweaver, и формы перестали корректно работать. Я снова все обработчики и отправщики проверила, всё заново переписала. Всё предполагает рабочее состояние, но результат не рабочий. Могу реанимировать одну только форму, и то - наполовину - без выделения полей и подсказок под полем. Если добавляю еще обработку следующей формы (в ajax form-scripts.js), то она на себя забирает все действия, производимые с предыдущей формой.

У каждой формы свой id и отдельный файл php-отправки.

Сайт: http://woodartlab.ru/

**HTML код формы:**

```
                <form role="form" id="contactForm4" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-toggle="validator">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group-lg col-sm-12">
                            <label for="name">Ваше имя:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name4" name="name4" placeholder="Имя" minlength="2" maxlength="30" required data-error="Как мы можем к вам обратиться?" >
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group-lg col-sm-12">
                            <label for="tel">Ваш контактный телефон:</label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone4" name="phone4" placeholder="+7 (XXX) XXX-XX-XX"  required data-error="На какой номер вам можно перезвонить?">
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group-lg col-sm-12">
                            <label for="email">Email адрес:</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email4" name="email4" placeholder="address@domen.ru" required data-error="На какой EMAIL отправить варианты макета?">
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group-lg col-sm-12">
                                <label for="styles4" class="control-label">Стиль обработки:</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="styles4" name="styles4">
                                  <option value="Постер">Постер</option>
                                  <option value="Исторический портрет">Исторический портрет</option>
                                  <option value="Цветокоррекция и фильтры">Цветокоррекция и фильтры</option>
                                  <option value="Коллаж">Коллаж</option>
                                  <option value="Модульная картина">Модульная картина</option>
                                </select>          
                        </div>                           
                        <div class="form-group-lg col-sm-12">
                                <label for="sizes4" class="control-label">Размер:</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="sizes4" name="sizes4">
                                    <optgroup label="Квадратные:">
                                          <option value="10x10">10x10</option>
                                          <option value="15x15">15x15</option>
                                          <option value="20x20">20x20</option>
                                          <option value="25x25">25x25</option>
                                          <option value="30x30" >30x30</option>
                                    </optgroup> 
                                    <optgroup label="Прямоугольные:">
                                          <option value="10x10">10x15</option>
                                          <option value="15x20">15x20</option>
                                          <option value="15x25">15x25</option>
                                          <option value="15x30">15x30</option>
                                          <option value="15x40">15x40</option>
                                          <option value="15x45">15x45</option>
                                          <option value="20x25">20x25</option>
                                          <option value="20x30">20x30</option>
                                          <option value="20x40">20x40</option>
                                          <option value="20x45">20x45</option>
                                          <option value="25x30">25x30</option>
                                          <option value="25x40">25x40</option>
                                          <option value="20x45">20x45</option>
                                          <option value="30x35">30x35</option>
                                          <option value="30x45">30x45</option>
                                    </optgroup>  
                                    <optgroup label="Составные/Модульные:">
                                          <option value="Модульная/Составная - 3 шт.">3 шт.</option>
                                          <option value="Модульная/Составная - 4 шт.">4 шт.</option>
                                          <option value="Модульная/Составная - 5 шт.">5 шт.</option>
                                          <option value="Модульная/Составная - 6 шт.">6 шт.</option>
                                          <option value="Модульная/Составная - 7 шт.">7 шт.</option>
                                          <option value="Модульная/Составная - 8 шт.">8 шт.</option>
                                          <option value="Модульная/Составная - более 8 шт.">более 8 шт.</option>
                                    </optgroup>                                  
                                </select>          
                        </div>                           
                    </div>
                        <div class="form-group-lg col-sm-12">
                        <p class="small">Мы не передаем ваши контактные данные третьим лицам. Соблюдаем Политику конфиденциальности персональных данных.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group-lg col-sm-12">
                         <button type="submit" id="form-submit4" class="btn btn-primary  bg-block btn-lg">Отправить заявку</button>
                         </div>
                    <div id="msgSubmit4" class=" text-center hidden"></div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </form>
```

**Ajax-обработчик** form-scripts.js :

```
//ФОРМА ПЕРВОГО ЭКРАНА//

$("#contactForm").validator().on("submit", function (event) {
    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...
        formError();
        submitMSG(false, "Проверьте поля ввода.");
    } else {
        // everything looks good!
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm();
    }
});

function submitForm(){
    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var phone = $("#phone").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/form-process.php",
        data: "name=" + name + "&phone=" + phone + "&email=" + email,
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
            } else {
                formError();
                submitMSG(false,text);
            }
        }
    });
}

function formSuccess(){
    $("#contactForm")[0].reset();
    submitMSG(true, "Сообщение отправлено!")
}

function formError(){
    $("#contactForm").removeClass().addClass('bounce animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
        $(this).removeClass();
    });
}

function submitMSG(valid, msg){
    if(valid){
        var msgClasses = "h3 text-center tada animated text-success";
    } else {
        var msgClasses = "h3 text-center text-danger";
    }
    $("#msgSubmit").removeClass().addClass(msgClasses).text(msg);
}


//ФОРМА ОБРАТНОГО ЗВОНКА//

$("#contactForm1").validator().on("submit", function (event) {
    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...
        formError();
        submitMSG(false, "Проверьте поле ввода.");
    } else {
        // everything looks good!
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm();
    }
});

function submitForm(){
    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var phone1 = $("#phone1").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/form-process1.php",
        data:  "&phone1=" + phone1,
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
            } else {
                formError();
                submitMSG(false,text);
            }
        }
    });
}

function formSuccess(){
    $("#contactForm1")[0].reset();
    submitMSG(true, "Сообщение отправлено!")
}

function formError(){
    $("#contactForm1").removeClass().addClass('bounce animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
        $(this).removeClass();
    });
}

function submitMSG(valid, msg){
    if(valid){
        var msgClasses = "text-center slideInUp animated text-success";
    } else {
        var msgClasses = "text-center text-danger";
    }
    $("#msgSubmit1").removeClass().addClass(msgClasses).text(msg);
}



//ФОРМА ЗАЯВКИ ИЗ БЛОКА СТИЛИ//
$("#contactForm2").validator().on("submit", function (event) {
    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...
        formError();
        submitMSG(false, "Проверьте поля ввода.");
    } else {
        // everything looks good!
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm();
    }
});

function submitForm(){
    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var name2 = $("#name2").val();
    var phone2 = $("#phone2").val();
    var email2 = $("#email2").val();
    var styles2 = $("#styles2").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/form-process2.php",
        data: "name2=" + name2 + "&phone2=" + phone2 + "&email2=" + email2 + "&styles2=" + styles2,
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
            } else {
                formError();
                submitMSG(false,text);
            }
        }
    });
}

function formSuccess(){
    $("#contactForm2")[0].reset();
    submitMSG(true, "Сообщение отправлено!")
}

function formError(){
    $("#contactForm2").removeClass().addClass('bounce animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
        $(this).removeClass();
    });
}

function submitMSG(valid, msg){
    if(valid){
        var msgClasses = "text-center slideInUp animated text-success";
    } else {
        var msgClasses = "text-center text-danger";
    }
    $("#msgSubmit2").removeClass().addClass(msgClasses).text(msg);
}




//ФОРМА ПОДПИСКИ//

$("#contactForm3").validator().on("submit", function (event) {
    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...
        formError();
        submitMSG(false, "Проверьте поле ввода.");
    } else {
        // everything looks good!
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm();
    }
});

function submitForm(){
    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var email3 = $("#email3").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/form-process3.php",
        data:  "&email3=" + email3,
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
            } else {
                formError();
                submitMSG(false,text);
            }
        }
    });
}

function formSuccess(){
    $("#contactForm3")[0].reset();
    submitMSG(true, "Сообщение отправлено!")
}

function formError(){
    $("#contactForm3").removeClass().addClass('bounce animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
        $(this).removeClass();
    });
}

function submitMSG(valid, msg){
    if(valid){
        var msgClasses = "text-center slideInUp animated text-success";
    } else {
        var msgClasses = "text-center text-danger";
    }
    $("#msgSubmit3").removeClass().addClass(msgClasses).text(msg);
}




//ФОРМА ЗАЯВКИ ИЗ БЛОКА РАЗМЕРЫ

$("#contactForm4").validator().on("submit", function (event) {
    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...
        formError();
        submitMSG(false, "Проверьте поля ввода.");
    } else {
        // everything looks good!
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm();
    }
});

function submitForm(){
    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var name4 = $("#name4").val();
    var phone4 = $("#phone4").val();
    var email4 = $("#email4").val();
    var styles4 = $("#styles4").val();
    var sizes4 = $("#sizes4").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/form-process4.php",
        data: "name4=" + name4 + "&phone4=" + phone4 + "&email4=" + email4 + "&styles4=" + styles4 + "&sizes4=" + sizes4,
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
            } else {
                formError();
                submitMSG(false,text);
            }
        }
    });
}

function formSuccess(){
    $("#contactForm4")[0].reset();
    submitMSG(true, "Сообщение отправлено!")
}

function formError(){
    $("#contactForm4").removeClass().addClass('bounce animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
        $(this).removeClass();
    });
}

function submitMSG(valid, msg){
    if(valid){
        var msgClasses = "h5 text-center slideInUp animated text-success";
    } else {
        var msgClasses = "h5 text-center text-danger";
    }
    $("#msgSubmit4").removeClass().addClass(msgClasses).text(msg);
}
```

**PHP-отправщик** (в данном случае - form-proccess4.php для #contactForm4):

```
<?php
$errorMSG = "";

// NAME
if (empty($_POST["name4"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Укажите ваше имя ";
} else {
    $name4 = $_POST["name4"];
}
// PHONE
if (empty($_POST["phone4"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Укажите телефон для связи";
} else {
    $phone4 = $_POST["phone4"];
}
// EMAIL
if (empty($_POST["email4"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Укажите email, на который мы вышлем макет";
} else {
    $email4 = $_POST["email4"];
}
// STYLES
if (empty($_POST["styles4"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Укажите желаемый стиль фотообработки";
} else {
    $styles4 = $_POST["styles4"];
}
// SIZES
if (empty($_POST["sizes4"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Укажите желаемый размер";
} else {
    $sizes4 = $_POST["sizes4"];
}



$EmailTo = "myemail@gmail.com";
$Subject = "ЗАЯВКА НА МАКЕТ  (форма блока размеры)";



// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Имя: ";
$Body .= $name4;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Телефон: ";
$Body .= $phone4;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $email4;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Стиль обработки: ";
$Body .= $styles4;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Размер: ";
$Body .= $sizes4;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email4);


// redirect to success page
if ($success && $errorMSG == ""){
   echo "success";
}else{
    if($errorMSG == ""){
        echo "Что-то пошло не так... :(";
    } else {
        echo $errorMSG;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: 1. не используйте Adobe Dreamweaver, используйте нормальный IDE, например PHPStorm. В PHPStorm есть постоянное автосохранение.
2. Отправляйте формы с помощью фукнций `ajaxSubmit`, `ajaxForm`, и не надо будет перечислять все поля